# script/delayed_job start is not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, delayed-job

I am getting the following error while running script/delayed_job start command

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Delayed::Worker
            load_missing_constant at c:/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:440
            load_missing_constant at c:/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:437
  const_missing_with_dependencies at c:/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:80
                        daemonize at c:/jruby-1.6.8/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.0.8/lib/delayed/command.rb:58
                           (root) at script/delayed_job:5
```

script/delayed_job contains the following code

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'config', 'environment'))
require 'delayed/command'
Delayed::Command.new(ARGV).daemonize
```

I am using 2.0.8 version delayed_job gem.My current rails version is 2.3.5.

Please help me for resolving this issue

Answer (score 2):

You should look at the README of the version 2.0.8 [here](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/tree/v2.0.8)

If using active_record do:

```
script/generate delayed_job
rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Actually while running rails generate delayed_job:active_record, I didn't get delayed_job script and migration file.So I have manually added those two files instead of running this generator

As per my observation this generator will be available for delayed_job 3.x version on wards

Could you please give some other solution ?

Comment: Updated my answer. Look at the readme of the version you are using https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/tree/v2.0.8

Comment: I have followed the above steps but still getting same issue.
I ran delayed_job/start command with jruby script/delayed_job start

I am using jruby on windows machine
Could you please let me know the solution for resolving this issue